# command line brings up code instead of running commands

Tags: truffle, command-line

I am trying to run truffle commands on commandline but it brings up the code file instead

like this

[image: Like this]

Comment: Try to run it from an other directory of your project (not from the directory where your truffle.js is)

Comment: @Andromelus this happens after I uninstalled and installed truffle   C:\Users\user>npm install -g truffle
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle -> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js
+ truffle@4.0.5
added 91 packages in 21.825s

C:\Users\user>truffle version
'truffle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.