# installed truffle but cannot run commands on commandline

Tags: truffle, command-line, truffle-config

followed up from [previous post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37422/command-line-brings-up-code-instead-of-running-commands?noredirect=1#comment41363_37422)

I installed truffle however this is what I get

> PS C:\Users\user> npm install -g truffle C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle ->
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.j
>   s
>   + truffle@4.0.5 updated 1 package in 3.018s
>
> PS C:\Users\user> truffle version truffle : The term 'truffle' is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
>   program.  Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
>   verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + truffle version
>   + ~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (truffle:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I have no idea why this is happening, I could run the commands if I went to node_modules/.bin/truffle but what is conflicting the commands right now?

Answer (score 2):

Set the path in environment variables:

[image: Environment Variables]